# Passing JSON type as parameter to SQL Server 2016 stored procedure using ADO.Net in ASP.Net Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, sql-server-2016

Can someone give example how to pass JSON type as parameter to SQL Server 2016 stored procedure using ADO.Net in C# ASP.Net Core Web Api project ? 
I want to see example of SQL Server 2016 stored procedure and pass of JSON type in C# ASP.Net Core Web Api.

Comment: Very good question. I want too

Comment: AFIAK, Sql server 2016 does not have a JSON data type, so you just pass your json to the stored procedure as a varchar. Inside the stored procedure you can use the [built in functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921897.aspx) that knows how to handle JSON data. You can see a code example in [this article.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/09/08/passing-arrays-to-t-sql-procedures-as-json/)

Comment: There are two sentences in your question and both of them say *exactly* the same thing. And then the title of your question says exactly the same thing *again*. Please clean up your question.

Answer (score 45):

There is no `json` data type in SQL Server you can simply send your `json` as `nvarchar(max)` to a stored procedure.

If you want to map your json to table you can use use `OPENJSON` to convert data to rows and columns.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SaveJSON
    @pID int,
    @pJson nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [YourTable] ([ID], [JSONData])
    VALUES (@pID, @pJson)
END
```

If you want to map json objects with table you can do this

```
//json would be something like this
[
 { "id" : 2,"name": "John"},
 { "id" : 5,"name": "John"}
]

INSERT INTO YourTable (id,Name)
SELECT id, name
FROM OPENJSON(@pJson)
WITH (id int,
name nvarchar(max))
```

[Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1087995/Inserting-JSON-Text-into-SQL-Server-Table) is a very good and detailed article which will give you detailed idea to deal with `json data`

Comment: As per expectation,thank you so much for this awesome solution

Comment: for add `JSON Data type' native vote this : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/41851870-add-json-data-type-for-design-table

Comment: Actually, the data type needs to be `nvarchar(max)` (not just `varchar` as you mentioned) - corrected

Comment: I have found that there are 2 requirements to use this nice little inline table function: 1. SQL Server 2016 and later and database compatibility >= 130 `select compatibility_level from sys.databases`

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server 2016 do have native JSON support - a new JSON datatype (which is based on `nvarchar`) is there, as well as a FOR JSON command to convert output from a query into JSON format

Microsoft did not include a separate JSON datatype - instead, there are a number of JSON functions (to package up database rows into JSON, or to parse JSON into relational data) which operate on columns of type `NVARCHAR(n)`

If you have JSON text, you can extract data from JSON or verify that JSON is properly formatted using built-in functions `JSON_VALUE`, `JSON_QUERY`, and `ISJSON`. For more advanced querying and analysis, the `OPENJSON` function can transform an array of JSON objects into a set of rows. Any SQL query can be executed on the returned result set. Finally, there is the `FOR JSON` clause that enables you to format query results as JSON text.

So, I recommend you use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` as your stored procedure parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple example that shows the C# and the SQL, please see:
https://chris.koester.io/index.php/2018/03/21/load-json-into-sql-server-using-a-stored-procedure-and-csharp/

You probably have some higher level data layer approach in your C#, like with EF or something, but this will let you get a simple test setup using a good ol' ADO.Net SQLCommand.